# Which algorithms exhibits Greedy Choice Property but not Optimal Substructure Property

Tags: greedy-algorithms, huffman-coding, dijkstras-algorithm

After a few courses using CLRS, I still have not been able to find a satisfying answer to the title question.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26440495/2291720) answer suggests Hoffman trees.  But here the greedy choice is the two subtrees with the lowest frequency.  I am however not convinced, that it does not exhibit OPS, since the optimal solution to the full problem is the solution to the subtree consisting of the merged two subtree with lowest frequency.  This way I remain convinced it does also exhibits OPS.

I found a suggestion of Dijkstra SSAD Shortest Path: But again I remain unconvinced: The Greedy Choice is the light edge across the cut and the shortest path to all vertices in the graph is the shortest path to the current set S (i.e. the subproblem) plus the shortest path from any of the vertices in S to the remaining vertices.  Again, this to me sounds a lot like OPS.

So what are some algorithms that exhibits GCP but not OPS.  Or is it the case that GCP implies OPS?